# Laravel 5.1 linking style sheet not working

Tags: laravel-5, stylesheet

I am probably missing something very simple but, when I link my style sheet I get:

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://laravel.dev:8000/public/css/masterCss.css">
```

showing on the webpage rather then linking to my css file.

My Html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The Nub Life</title>

    {{ Html::style('/public/css/masterCss.css') }}

</head>
<body>

@yield('content')

</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

the stylesheet href url, should not contain the word **public**. this is how you can generate url for your css asset files

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/masterCss.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a .css file in your public/your_project_name/css/style.css

Simply write

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('your_project_name/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```